# Find the regex used by HTML5 forms for validation

Tags: regex, html

Some HTML5 input elements accept the `pattern` attribute, which is a regex for form validation. Some other HTML5 input elements, such as, `input type=email` does the validation automatically.

Now it seems that the way validation is handled is different accross browsers. Given a specific browser, say Chrome, is it possible to programmatically extract the regex used for validation? Or maybe there is documentation out there?

Comment: @jfriend00 Take a look here : http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: @jfriend00: It depends on what your notion of a "valid email address" is. As indicated in [this answer][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses/201378#201378], RFC822 can be covered by a regex, though RFC5322 cannot. HTML5 specifies a much narrower notion of a "valid email address" which can be validated using a regex (see my answer).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [HTML5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#valid-e-mail-address) currently lists a valid email address as one matching the ABNF:

```
1*( atext / "." ) "@" ldh-str *( "." ldh-str )
```

which is elucidated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940120/is-there-a-java-implementation-of-the-html5-input-email-validation). [@SLaks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940120/is-there-a-java-implementation-of-the-html5-input-email-validation/4940155#4940155) provides a regex equivalent.

That said, with a little digging through the source, shows that [WebKit implemented](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/html/EmailInputType.cpp?rev=86298) email address validation using basically the same regex as [SLaks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940120/is-there-a-java-implementation-of-the-html5-input-email-validation/4940155#4940155), i.e.,

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*
```

However, there is no requirement that email addresses be validated by a regex. For example, [Mozilla (Gecko)](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/cf5da681d577/content/html/content/src/nsHTMLInputElement.cpp#l3967) implemented email validation using a pretty basic [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Hence, there needn't be a regex involved in email validation.

Comment: [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*
matches 
word_word.word@word
in FF9 linux

Comment: @jpse: If you read the linked spec above, you'll note that it states that it *willfully violates RFC 5322*, or, in other words, the validation used for HTML email fields fails to match some valid email addresses and matches some strings that are not valid email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 spec now gives a (non-normative) regex which is supposed to exactly match all email addresses that it specifies as valid. There's a copy of it on my blog here:
http://blog.gerv.net/2011/05/html5_email_address_regexp/
and in the spec itself:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#e-mail-state-(type=email))

The version above is incorrect only in that it does not limit domain components to max 255 characters and does not prevent them beginning or ending with a "-".

Gerv

Comment: Could you link the regex instead of linking to your blog which could end up not resolving one day?

Comment: The HTML5 spec is the best place to go for a permalink: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#e-mail-state-(type=email) .

Answer (score -1):

this works for me:
pattern="[^@]+@[^@]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}"